# eslint-webpack-plugin not displaying errors or warnings

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, eslint

Eslint seems to not be working when using with webpack. I am not quite too sure why it's not displaying anything. I am testing it with an unused variable. If you have any tips it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Everything works fine with the webpack, its just not linting and is quite
annoying.

**webpack config:**

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ESLintPlugin = require('eslint-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = (options) => ({
  mode: options.mode,
  entry: options.entry,
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'build'),
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  stats: {
    preset: 'normal',
    moduleTrace: true,
    errorDetails: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/i,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: [
                '@babel/preset-env',
                '@babel/preset-react',
              ],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'html-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mp4|webm)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 10000,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: options.plugins.concat([
    // Always expose NODE_ENV to webpack, in order to use `process.env.NODE_ENV`
    // inside your code for any environment checks; Terser will automatically
    // drop any unreachable code.
    // new ESLintPlugin(options),
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({
      NODE_ENV: 'development',
    }),
    new ESLintPlugin({ extensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx'] }),
  ]),
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    compress: true,
    open: true,
    overlay: true,
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.react.js'],
  },
});
```

Basic eslint:

**.eslintrc**

```json
{
    "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
    "extends": [
        "airbnb",
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "plugin:react-hooks/recommended"
    ],
    "env": {
        "browser": true
    },
    "rules": {
        "react/jsx-filename-extension": [
            1,
            {
                "extensions": [
                    ".js",
                    ".jsx"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "import/no-cycle": "off"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has to do with square brackets. I had square brackets wrapped around a folder in the directory path and that seemed to cause eslint to break.